# angular/jasmine: Error: Expected spy to have been called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

The code exists here https://review.openstack.org/#/c/418828/ but I will go into more detail below:

I am writing tests for this particular piece of code: https://review.openstack.org/#/c/418828/26/openstack_dashboard/static/app/core/network_qos/qos.service.js

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('horizon.app.core.network_qos')
    .factory('horizon.app.core.network_qos.service', qosService);

  qosService.$inject = [
    '$filter',
    'horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api.neutron',
    'horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api.userSession'
  ];

  /*
  * @ngdoc factory
  * @name horizon.app.core.network_qos.service
  *
  * @description
  * This service provides functions that are used through the QoS
  * features.  These are primarily used in the module registrations
  * but do not need to be restricted to such use.  Each exposed function
  * is documented below.
  */
  function qosService($filter, neutron, userSession) {
    var version;

    return {
      getPolicyPromise: getPolicyPromise,
      getPoliciesPromise: getPoliciesPromise
    };

     /*
      * @ngdoc function
      * @name getPoliciesPromise
      * @description
      * Given filter/query parameters, returns a promise for the matching
      * policies.  This is used in displaying lists of policies.  In this case,
      * we need to modify the API's response by adding a composite value called
      * 'trackBy' to assist the display mechanism when updating rows.
      */
    function getPoliciesPromise(params) {
      return userSession.get().then(getQoSPolicies);

      function getQoSPolicies() {
        return neutron.getQoSPolicies(params).then(modifyResponse);
      }

      function modifyResponse(response) {
        return {data: {items: response.data.items.map(modifyQos)}};

        function modifyQos(policy) {
          policy.trackBy = policy.id;
          policy.apiVersion = version;
          policy.name = policy.name || policy.id;
          return policy;
        }
      }
    }

    /*
    * @ngdoc function
    * @name getPolicyPromise
    * @description
    * Given an id, returns a promise for the policy data.
    */
    function getPolicyPromise(identifier) {
      neutron.getVersion().then(setVersion);
      return neutron.getQosPolicy(identifier).then(modifyResponse);

      function modifyResponse(response) {
        response.data.apiVersion = version;
        return {data: response.data};
      }
    }
  }

})();
```

This is my current test file:

```
 (function() {
  "use strict";

  describe('qosService', function() {
    var service;
    beforeEach(module('horizon.app.core'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
      service = $injector.get('horizon.app.core.network_qos.service');
    }));

    describe('getPoliciesPromise', function() {
      it("provides a promise that gets translated", inject(function($q, $injector, $timeout) {
        var neutron = $injector.get('horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api.neutron');
        var session = $injector.get('horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api.userSession');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var deferredSession = $q.defer();
        spyOn(neutron, 'getQoSPolicies').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
        spyOn(session, 'get').and.returnValue(deferredSession.promise);
        var result = service.getPoliciesPromise({});
        deferred.resolve({
          data: {
            items: [{id: 123, name: 'policy1'}]
          }
        });
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(neutron.getQoSPolicies).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result.$$state.value.data.items[0].name).toBe('policy1');
      }));
    });

  });

})();
```

When I run the tests I currently get errors saying:

```
Expected spy getQoSPolicies to have been called.
```

As you can see, getQoSPolicies is definitely called. If anyone can see what is wrong with the tests to give me that error it would be much appreciated!! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be resolving following promise (`deferredSession`) along with `neutron` one, or it won't go inside `.then` of `userSession.get().then(getQoSPolicies)`:

```
var deferredSession = $q.defer();
spyOn(session, 'get').and.returnValue(deferredSession.promise);
...
...

deferredSession.resolve({});
deferred.resolve(...);
$timeout.flush();
```

Resolve that along with the existing and it should work as you expect!

Comment: @BethElwell glad I could help! :)